# Visual Basic 2010 - Multiple Checkbox calculations with a set price

Tags: vb.net

So I am trying to program something where you have $200 dollars already and in one groupbox i have 3 different options as checkboxes to buy something, also one groupbox has radibuttons where you can only choose 1 out of 3 options. All items have different costs...

What i have done already:
I have coded

```
 Dim money As Integer = 200

 Private Sub chkBoots_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBoots.CheckedChanged
        lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 20
    End Sub

Private Sub chkJacket_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkJacket.CheckedChanged
        lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 40
    End Sub

Private Sub chkUmbrella_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkUmbrella.CheckedChanged
        lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 10
    End Sub

  Private Sub rdbCreditCard_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbCreditCard.CheckedChanged
        lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 20
    End Sub

Private Sub rdbDebitCard_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbDebitCard.CheckedChanged
        lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 20
    End Sub
```

The problem is that whenever more than one checkbox and a radiobutton is selected it only subtracts the assigned cost of each checkbox or radiobutton from $200, instead of subtracting every checkbox and radiobutton cost selected from $200... ( for example if you press Jacket and Boots it will only subtract just one of those costs instead of both of them from $200)

THANK YOU SO MUCH ALL HELP IS APPRECIATED!!!!

Comment: It is working the way you coded it.  if you want to subtract from Money, do so rather than just displaying the result *as if* you deducted.  Also turn on Option Strict: you are subtracting an integer from a double and assigning to a string

Comment: You also need to be checking the state of the checkbox. The CheckChanged event fires every time the check status changes, from checked to unchecked and unchecked to checked.

Answer (score 0):

right now you are just updating the label text in the Subs. You need to update the money variable as well.

add

```
 money = money - price
```

in all the Subs for whatever the price happens to be in each Sub.

Answer (score 0):

You did a great job on showing the price correctly but forgot to do the REAL CALCULATION.

Here is probably what you want:

```
Dim money As Integer = 200

Private Sub chkBoots_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkBoots.CheckedChanged
    lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 20
    money -= 20
End Sub

Private Sub chkJacket_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkJacket.CheckedChanged
    lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 40
    money -= 40
End Sub

Private Sub chkUmbrella_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkUmbrella.CheckedChanged
    lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 10
    money -= 10
End Sub

Private Sub rdbCreditCard_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbCreditCard.CheckedChanged
    lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 20
    money -= 20
End Sub

Private Sub rdbDebitCard_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdbDebitCard.CheckedChanged
    lblAmountOfMoney.Text = Val(money) - 20
    money -= 20
End Sub
```